# Issue With New Timber 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

While I was trying to use **stetho-timber Library** in my Android application I faced this problem:

> Error:Module 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-timber:1.3.1' depends on one
>   or more Android Libraries but is a jar

After inspecting in its codes I found that it uses timber v3.0.1!

Comment: Please don't caps lock your posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your build.gradle dependencies tag to exclude timber within the stetho library,
cause it is an old version and conflicts with new one:

```
dependencies {  
    compile ("com.facebook.stetho:stetho-timber:1.3.1") {  
        exclude group: "com.jakewharton.timber", module: "timber"  
    }  
    .  
    .  
    .
```